# QT error: cannot find libs

Tags: c++, qt

Hi tried to set up my environment to run QT 4.8.3 aimed at the GCC compiler (so reading the .a files) The problem is it is now throwing the errors:

```
:-1: error: cannot find -lQtGuid
:-1: error: cannot find -lQtCored
collect2.exe:-1: error: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Maybe it can't find the core and gui dll's? My environment variables point to the 4.8.3 bin directory? Am I missing anything?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My project was set up with the msvc compiler when in fact I had configured Qt for mingw g++ so I switched it to the GCC compiler.

Answer (score 19):

Try this,

```
sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev
```

Answer (score 5):

this one is working for me

```
sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev
```